# Mysql list data from left join query

Tags: mysql, join, php

I have 2 table and i want to pull data from both of them.
This is sample for my table structure:

Table tbl_a = id, time, note, customer
Table tbl_b = id, time, name, surname, note

This is my mysql request:

```
Select * from tbl_a left join tbl_b on tbl_a.customer=tbl.b=id where tbl_a.id=5;
```

When i run this query directly from mysql i can see result exactly as i want but i dont know how to display it in my php page.

i am doing it like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("Select * from tbl_a left join tbl_b on tbl_a.customer=tbl.b=id where tbl_a.id=5");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

echo $data[id]." - ".$data[time]." - ".$data[note]." - ".$data[customer]." - ".$data[id]." - ".$data[name]." - ".$data[surname]." - ".$data[note];
```

i know that column names that are repeated could not be used again but i dont know what the right way is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest instead of using the `ALL` (*). just type the column names with an `AS` attached such as: `TableA`.`id` AS `TableAId`,`TableB`.`id` AS `TableBId` and so on.

Comment: Thank you a lot. is there any quicker way to do that becouse i have about 40 column? if not i will use your suggestion

Comment: Not that I know of. hopefully someone can shed some light if there's a way.